# Why can't I access this std::string that's declared in an anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

My understanding is that anonymous namespaces are an idiomatic c++ way of solving certain problems (i.e. what C# and Java solve with static classes).

In the following example, I am attempting to access a `std::string` which is declared in an anonymous namespace, but I get a compile-time error that `aString` "does not name a type"

I have tried changing the line in question to `std::string aString = "some text";`, but this results in the compiler complaining that `aString` is ambiguous.

Is it possible to forward declare a variable in an anonymous namespace like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string

namespace{
    std::string aString;
}

aString = "some text";

int main()
{
    std::cout << "aString = " << aString << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: You can't run arbitrary code in the global space.  `aString = "some text";` is an assignment so that needs to be done in block scope.

Comment: You could initialize your string, though: `std::string aString("some text");`

Comment: So after initializing it, the only way to modify `aString` is through some function that's defined in the same translation unit?

Comment: @wesanyer Yes.  You can't run code in the global space.  All you can do is declare and define things and if you do define a variable you can initialize it as part of the definition.

Comment: @wesanyer Yes.  You can't run code in the global space.  All you can do is declare and define things and if you do define a variable you can initialize it as part of the definition.

Comment: You can't run arbitrary code in *any* namespace. Most code is only allowed to appear inside a function.

Comment: Ok. Thank you all for the help and for identifying this as a duplicate.